# Does map method in scala collections obeys order of source

Tags: scala, collections

Consider the following example:

```
List(0,3,2,1) map List("A","B","C","D")
```

it gives `List(A, D, C, B)`

Whether this order is maintained always or it can change the order for a different execution.

I want reorder the list by a generator function(index generator).
 Whether we can assume the order of map method or is it undecidable?

Comment: The order here depend on the order of the indexes in the first list, if you have `List(0, 1, 2, 3)` the output would be `List(A, B, C D)`, that map desugarize to `index => chars.apply(index)`.

Comment: It is true, but whether that order is always maintained?

Comment: Yes, of course, the order is maintained. Otherwise, it will be a pretty useless function.